# Lower bounds on covering numbers for sparse vectors

Tags: probability, references, high-dimensional, probability-inequalities, geometry

Consider the set $S_k$, which is defined as the subset of $k$-sparse vectors
in the unit sphere in $d$ dimensions:

$$
S_k \triangleq \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \| x \|_2 = 1, \, \left|\operatorname{supp}(x)\right| \leq k \right\}
$$

From [1], we know that $S_k$ admits an $\varepsilon$-net, $\mathcal{N}_\varepsilon$, of cardinality at most
$\left( \frac{C d}{k \varepsilon} \right)^k$, where $C$ is a constant, for $k \leq \frac{d}{2}$. Hence, its metric entropy satisfies

$$
\sqrt{ \log | \mathcal{N}_\varepsilon| } \leq \sqrt{k \log (cd / k \varepsilon)}.
$$

Is there a corresponding lower bound for $| \mathcal{N}_\varepsilon |$ that
differs from the upper bound by at most a logarithmic factor?

[1]: Roman Vershynin, *On the Role of Sparsity in Compressed Sensing and Random Matrix Theory*, *arXiv preprint [abs/0908.0257](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0257)*.

Comment: I am accustomed to thinking of $\operatorname{supp}(x)$ as a set rather than a number. Might you have meant $\left|\operatorname{supp} (x) \right| \le k$ rather than $\operatorname{supp}(x) \le k \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: You're right, that was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a typesetting oddity: Notice that these look different from each other: $$ \begin{align} & \ldots, \, |\operatorname{supp}(x)| \le k \\ & \ldots, \, \left|\operatorname{supp}(x)\right| \le k \end{align} $$